# Вывод графика plotly при помощи оконного приложения

Tags: python, tkinter, plotly

пишу небольшую программку с двумя кнопками: одна для загрузки данных, а вторая для экспорта графика plotly в файл на компьютере. Не понимаю что делаю не так, при сохранении, в указанном месте появляется пустой файл и открывается график в браузере. После превращения кода в .exe файл вторая кнопка не делает вообще ничего.

````
def but1():
fig = go.Figure(data=data, layout=layout)
    file = fd.asksaveasfile(mode='w', defaultextension=".html",
                            filetypes=(("HTML file", "*.html"), ("All Files", "*.*")))
    if file:
        file.write(py.plot(fig))
        file.close()
root = Tk()
but0 = Button(root, text="(●'◡'●)", command=but0, height=2, width=10)
but1 = Button(root, text="¯\_(ツ)_/¯", command=but1, height=2, width=10)
label = Label(root, text="выбери файл")
label.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky=W)
but0.grid(row=2, column=1, sticky=W)
but1.grid(row=2, column=2, sticky=W)
root.geometry("150x120")
root.mainloop()```
````